# Net force from ground on man

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

In given picture I can't understand why 10 m/s2 is being added or even included. If anything it must be subtracted since direction of acceleration due to ground is opposite to that of gravity.Moreover gravitational force acts on him due to Earth and not ground.Please help(imagine you had to do the sum without seeing the solution)

[image: sum from an exam]

Comment: What about after she has landed and is no longer decelerating?  What is the average force from the ground on her then?  In that case it's obvious that you need to include the $10\, \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$, so why not here?  Note that it's $+10$ instead of $-10$ because they have evidently chosen up as the positive direction; gravitational forces act downward, but you care about the upward force of the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parachutist hits the ground with a kinetic energy of $1/2 m v^2$. An average force $F$ acts on him due to the ground in order to slow him down. The real force is not constant over time, but we define $F$ as the constant force which would be needed to achieve the same result.
At the end of the fall the kinetic energy is 0. 
The only acting forces during the process are friction from the ground ($F$) and gravity ($mg$), which are opposite so that the total force $F_T=F-mg$.

By conservation of energy $W=\Delta K $ (the total work is equal to the variation of kinetic energy)

and since $W=F_T d$ (where $d$ is the distance over which $F$ acts) one gets

$$F_T d=Fd-mgd=\Delta K = K_{fin}-K_{in}= 0-1/2mv^2$$
so that
$$F={mv^2 \over 2d}+mg = 1335 N\sim1350N$$ so the answer is C.

I used conservation of energy, but another way is using the formula

$a={(v^2_f-v^2_{in})\over 2d}=-8m/s^2$ which is what you are suggested to do. This gives you the average acceleration (upwards) of the fall.
This acceleration is partly due to gravity and partly to friction. Thus again
$$F_T=F-mg=ma$$ so that $F=m(a+g)$ and you retain your solution. The accelarations appear to be summed because of the opposite signs...
$a$ is the *total* acceleration (upwards). Since friction has to both overcome gravity and add something to slow you down, the acceleration due to $F$ is given by summing $g$ and $a$.

Note that the two procedures, if you think about it, are actually the same as the formula $a={(v^2_f-v^2_{in})\over 2d}$ your book is using is $F_Td=mad=\Delta K$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the parachutist is decelerating. Therefore, the *net* force must be pointed upwards. The net force must be 600 Newton, upwards, to give a 8m/s2 deceleration.

However, there are two forces acting on the parachutist. There's gravity (750N downwards) and the normal force from the ground upwards. Therefore, the correct answer is [C]: 1350N upwards plus 750N downwards equals a net force of 600N upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write out Newton's 2nd law:

$$\sum F=ma \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n-mg=ma \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n=mg+ma$$

You can here see, why you *add* $g$ with $a$. Always write out the full equation before concluding what is going on.